# How can i import raster image to GRASS GIS without losing RGB Values?

Tags: raster, grass-gis

I am using GrassGIS 6.4.2, How can I import raster data to GrassGIS without losing RGB Values?

The raster image format is TIFF, the below commmand is using to import raster image:

```
r.in.gdal input=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\renjith\satellite\14feb06053537-s2as-053712‌​789010_01_p004.tif
```

After importing raster image I am getting like this

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange. Can you please provide more information: what is the format of the raster data, what commands are you using in GrassGIS and how are the RGB values being lost? Can you provide a screenshot of the before/after raster, etc.

Comment: Please use the **edit** button to revise your question with this additional information.

Answer (score 1):

Use [r.composite](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.composite.html) to merge the bands back into a single raster.

This is the example from the documentation page:

```
r.composite blue=lsat7_2002_10 green=lsat7_2002_20 
    red=lsat7_2002_30 output=lsat7_2002_rgb
```

Don't forget to set your region!